# java prettifier for html

Tags: java, html

I'm looking for something that I can use to prettify Java code for html. Some sites have them built in. I want it to alternate background colors, have a download source option, and be formatted for java. I would like this in either a css class or iframe format.
*Edit*
I want to use this on blogspot.com.

Comment: Take a look at http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might check out http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/ .. i think that's what stackoverflow uses for it's syntax highlighting.

If that doesn't suite your fancy, there are lots of options:

http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

http://craig.is/making/rainbows/

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-chili-js/

and others i'm sure, just search for javascript syntax highlighter